# Segmentation fault in std::string::size() const ()?

Tags: c++, gdb

I was writing a program that tell the user to input a random string, and then print out all the duplicates and the number of time each of them repeats. I was running it through gdb and this is the output:

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //Read a string word by word and put into a vector
  //loop through the vector:
  //  If there are two words duplicate:
  //    loop through another vector (used to store duplicate word)
  //    compare if these two words are the same as the duplicate word stored
  //      If the same: ++count[i]
  //      If not: push_back(count) ; ++count[i]

  string word;
  vector<string> sentence;
  vector<string> duplicate;
  vector<int> times;
  int count = 1;

  while (cin >> word) {
    if (word == "ctrlz") {
      break;
    }
  sentence.push_back(word);    
  }

  vector<string>::size_type i = 0;
  vector<string>::size_type j = 0;

  while (i != sentence.size()) {
    if (sentence[i] == sentence[i+1]) {
      while (j != sentence.size()) {
        if (duplicate.size() == 0) {
          duplicate.push_back(sentence[i]);
          times.push_back(count);
          ++times[0];
        }
        else { 
          if (sentence[i] != duplicate[j]) {
            duplicate.push_back(sentence[i]);
            times.push_back(count);
            ++times[j+1];          
          }
          else {
            ++times[j];
          }
        }
      ++j;
      }
    }
  ++i;  
  }

  while (i != duplicate.size()) {
    cout << duplicate[i] << ' ';
    ++i;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I got this after running gdb:

```
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /home/phongcao/C++/6.12
phong phong phong phong phong phong 
ctrlz

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x001c58d9 in std::string::size() const () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 
(gdb)
```

What does this output mean? How can I fix this segmentation fault?

Comment: Show the code and we'll be able to help you more. Odds are the code has a buffer overflow somewhere or it's `delete`ing or `free`ing something it shouldn't.

Comment: I suspect your program has overwritten the stack - but we need to see some code to suggest things - or you need to run valgrind or similar

Comment: 95% you're not handling memory properly, 5% your version of GCC has bugs in its string implementation.

Comment: @AbiusX 5% is awfully generous.

Comment: out of like a 100 times i've encountered segmentation fault errors, like 50 of them were due to GCC bugs. :) Thats my personal experience.

Comment: Did you turn on all the compiler warnings and make sure the code compiled with no warnings.

Comment: I already add the code in there!

Comment: @AbiusX: I will call you on that. Anytime anybody has complained it was a compiler bug to me it has always (apart from twice in 30 years) been the programmers fault.

Comment: @AbiusX: no way.  Anyone would expect not more than 1 in 1000 distinct segfaults being due to a compiler bug.

Comment: @questioner : debug your code to figure out which exact line is causing the error.

Comment: @Martin: Try a program that allocates/frees a small memory for a million times. Try to write into the array every time. You'll see for yourself. I've been working on Garbage and Dangling pointers and programming for 15 years, I doubt its my error!

Comment: @AbiusX Are you sure the allocation doesn't fail?

Comment: @Martin: yep, everytime pointer is set to zero, if (pointer) delete []pointer; then re-allocate

Comment: @AbiusX: Sounds like a memory fragmentation issue on your platform or failing a bounds check to me

Comment: @Martin: I strongly doubt that OS X and Ubuntu 10.10 both have fragmentation or paging issues and GCC is correct on both!

Comment: @AbiusX: Man give it up. At 23 you don't have 15 years of experience. You just shot yourself in the foot credibility wise. Its obviously a developer error not a compiler problem. (Since I have come across 2 compiler bugs in 30 years and I worked with gcc 2.95 I doubt you have seen any real ones and I will put it down to a workman blaming his tools rather than using valgrind). What this has to do with page fragmentation I don't know or care about. The bug is in the developers code.

Comment: @Martin: If you think your age makes you right, you're terribly wrong. Take a peek at my resume page at abiusx.com/resume . I've been developing since 10. I've been teaching at college for 5 years now :)

Comment: @AbiusX: No. I think your inexperience makes you wrong. I think your claims without proof make you wrong. I think you are wrong because the bug is obvious (its in the code). Every claim I have come across that blaims the compiler (apart from 2) have always been show to be in the user code. Its usally shoddy handling of pointers or overrunning the end of the array. I bet every time you have claimed this nonsense valgrind would have shown you were wrong. To claim its a compiler bug you better also come up with the appropriate bug number to show you know what you are talking about

Comment: @AbiusX: I think statements like: `5% your version of GCC has bugs` and `50 of them were due to GCC bugs` and `1 in 1000 distinct segfaults being due to a compiler bug` are silly without proof. Statements like `Sounds like a memory fragmentation issue` are irrelevant to the question and all in all show a lack of experience in real programming. If you had published a paper on the subject or had some real proof then you may get my attention but the exaggeration about 15 years of experience just gives it away.

Comment: @Martin: In fairness to Abius the memory fragmentation was something I suggested. My point was that with lots of rapid re-allocations you can begin to get memory fragmentation. When I've seen it before, this was on a linux-based RTOS and the memory allocations were a mixture of sizes. All of that was just a possible cause of problems with the test Abius suggested and as you quite rightly point out, nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @Martin: Well, from your anger I can easily guess that you're a programmer with average error in 100 LOC. My test results indicate i have below 1 errors in 100 lines of codes. Thats why all your problems with GCC were programmers fault and not mine.

Comment: @Martin: You expect a logical answer for a casual question? please refer to the GCC changelog for a huge list of bugs that were fixed in time. Also FYI, my comment there is not wrong. If you inspect the code, the "" memory (one byte null terminated string) is wasted.

Comment: @AbiusX: You made a claim. I expect you to back it up. I am aware of the GCC bug list (it has an experimental C++0x compiler attached). I challenge you to find even one that affected you (any one will do, even one not related to this question). And your comment is wrong. See 'Jonathan Sternberg' following comment. You should stick to languages you know (PHP).

Comment: @Martin: code my program, and you shall see that its right. I think you should stick to bugging others, cuz u know no langs.

Comment: @AbiusX: Sorry. Obviously this has gone beyond being useful. I tend to call people out that blame the compiler to prove it (one of my bad points). I apologize for being over-harsh and critical and I bear no resentment and hope to see further contributions from you on SO.

Comment: Thanks, and i'm also sorry for being rude. But its not appropriate to insult people only cuz they're young. I'm new to StackOverflow but not new to the computer world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some bugs:

```
if (sentence[i] == sentence[i+1]) {
```

Your loop permits i to be `size()-1` - So you're reading one past the end of the vector sentence.

```
while (i != sentence.size()) {
    while (j != sentence.size()) {
     ...
     ++j;
   }
   ++i;
}
```

j is never reset - next iteration of the outer loop it'll start at `sentence.size()` - You likely don't want that.

You should solve this with a `std::map<std::string, int>`:

```
std::map<std::string, int> words;
while (cin >> word) {
    if (word == "ctrlz") {
         break;
    }
    words[word] += 1;
}
for (std::map<std::string>::const_iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); ++it) { 
     if (it->second > 1) {
         cout << it->second << " copies of " << it->first << endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `g++` is being used, adding `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to compile line is a good way to catch such bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running it in gdb, run it in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (technically "memcheck" is the name of the default tool it comes with).  This will probably point right away to the source of your problems (which may or may not be exactly the place where it finally crashes).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here: `if (sentence[i] == sentence[i+1])`

On the last iteration of the loop, `i == sentence.size()-1`, and `i+1 == sentence.size()` which is outside the bounds of the vector.

In addition, `++times[j+1];` assumes you've already `push_back`ed `j+2` integers, but on the first time through the loop, you've only `push_back`ed `j+1` integers.

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation Fault happens when you try to access (read/write) memory that is far away from your programs variables, e.g:

```
char s[100];
int a=100000;
s[a]=2;
```

So you should be looking for array indexes, and pointers and ensure they're pointing to your application memories. Also sending small arrays or unallocated pointers to functions that assume they have enough memory causes the same error (inside that function).

string.h functions assume you have made memory for them.